# How can I set a value input that uses the v-model? - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

How can I set a value input that uses the v-model?
I Googled for this problem but not solved
I have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="customer_email" v-model="form.customer_email" id="email">
```

I need to set this input value to `{{ auth()->user()->email }}`

Comment: did you try out `<input type="text" :value="{{auth()->user()->email}}" name="customer_email" v-model="form.customer_email" id="email">`

Comment: yes, not worked

Comment: try to remove `:` from `value="{{...}}"`

Comment: doesn't work, read this page: [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) - I don't know how can I use from data in javasacript, i tried some times but it not solved

Comment: could you get that `email` using REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using two way data binding `v-model`, you can simply set this value in the vue end.

```
let app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                customer_email: "{{ auth()->user()->email }}",
                ......
                ......
            }
        }
    },
    ......
    ......
});
```

Comment: the vue file is very big, and I confused; is there any way I solve this problem with the blade file? for example can I use from `<script>your code</script>` in the blade file?

Comment: where is your vue file?? how you are using vue in this blade?? in your vue code there should be a code block as mine if you are using it correctly.. you have to do it this way

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS :)

```
  data() {
        return {
            form: {
                customer_email: "",
            
            }
        }
    },methods:{
     
 user(){
axios.get("api/profile").then(({data})=>{
(this.user = data)

this.form.customer_emeail = this.user.email
})

},

},created(){
  this.user();
}
```

> In your controller add this

```
   public function profile()
    {
    return auth('api')->user();
    }
```

then put this in your api.php

```
Route::get('profile','YourController@profile');
```